# Replacing substrings across two strings

Tags: javascript

I have the following 2 strings and I would like to replace the occurrence of a word with another word. Here is an example:

```
var str1 = 'My name is {{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}'
var str2 = 'Me llamo * *'

var result = solution(str1, str2)

assert(result, 'Me llamo {{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}')
```

Here, I would like to replace each asterisk with the appropriate template.

Comment: Are str1 and str2 always like this?

Comment: @TobiasK. No, they are not always the same. But, they have this same pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this ES6 function, using a `replace` callback argument:

```js
function solution (str1, str2) {
    var replacements = str1.match(/\{\{.*?\}\}/g);
    return str2.replace(/\*/g, match => replacements.shift() || '');
}

// test case
var str1 = 'My name is {{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}';
var str2 = 'Me llamo * *';
// match
var result = solution(str1, str2);
// output
console.log(result);
```

The asterisks that do not have a double-brace-pair counter part are simply deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to get all of the variables and replace each * with the variable at each index:

```js
var target = 'My name is {{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}';
var translation = 'Me llamo * *';

function translate(from, to) {
    var interpolations = from.match(/(\{\{([\w\s]+)\}\})/g);
    return to.replace(/\*/g, function(matches) {
       return interpolations.shift()
    })
}

console.log(translate(target, translation));
```

Comment: Code snippets have a nice feature of showing the entries of `console.log` items. I've tried to avoid using `alert()` since I've found that feature exists.

Comment: Ahhh, good to know (updated)! Thanks @FrankerZ - I always feel gross using alert :P

Comment: It seems like your solution has evolved to what I posted. ;-)

Comment: @trincot, lol - just the `shift()` call, that was much better than using a temporary counter variable. We just happened to come up with similar solutions. If you want to add an ES5 version to your answer I'm happy to remove mine :)

Answer (score 0):

If both strings are always like you examples, then:

```js
var str1 = 'My name is {{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}'
var str2 = 'Me llamo * *'

var result = solution(str1, str2)

console.log(result)
console.log(result == 'Me llamo {{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}')

function solution(str1, str2){
  return str2.substr(0, str2.length-3) + str1.substr('My name is '.length)
}
```

Comment: If both strings are always the same, then what would be the point of making a function then?

Comment: Both strings are not the same. They follow the same pattern though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `Array.prototype.replace` function.

```
var str1 = 'My name is {{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}';
var str2 = 'Me llamo * *';

var result = solution(str1, str2);

console.log(result);

function solution(str1, str2){
    str1 = str1.match(/\{\{.*?\}\}/g);
    return str2.replace(/\*/g, () => str1.shift());
}
```

However, I think it will be more useful to remove `{{}}` tags from string. You can achieve it as following:

```
function solution(str1, str2){
    str1 = str1.match(/\{\{.*?\}\}/g).map(m => m.match(/\{\{\s(.*)\s\}\}/)[1]);
    return str2.replace(/\*/g, () => str1.shift());
}
```

Comment: ... and another copy of the same solution ;-)

Comment: @trincot It isn't copy. Firstly, you created a new variable inside function scope, which is unnecesary. Secondly, I think that leaving `{{}}` characters inside a string is not exactly what OP wants, so I improved it too.

Answer (score 0):

An iterative and less abbreviated (but probably slower) version that is more tolerant to mismatches in the number of * or {{}}:

```js
var solution = function(s1, s2) {
  var myRegexp = /(\{\{.*?\}\})/g;
  var match = myRegexp.exec(s1);
  while (match != null && s2.indexOf('*')!== -1) {
    s2 = s2.replace('*', match[1]);
    match = myRegexp.exec(s1);
  };
  return s2;
};


var str1 = 'My name is {{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}';
var str2 = 'Me llamo *  *';

var result = solution(str1, str2);
console.log(result);
```